# Changing size of UIImagePicker presented via UIPopOver (iPad)

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to change the size of a UIImagePicker which I am presenting via a UIPopOver. The code is shown below. The issue is that the PopOver size doesn't display properly - it briefly flashes up in the correct size, then animates down to the usual default size.

Can anybody advise me on how I can change the size of the popover ?

```
- (void)showImagePickerForPhotoLibrary {
    NSLog(@"Picker");
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePickerController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(768, 1000);

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController");
        if (cls != nil) {
            popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
            //popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(768, 1000);
            [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:selectedRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:4 animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else {
        [app.mainViewController presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the most elegant solution, however it seems to work fine for me:

You can embed the UIImagePickerController's view into a "container" UIViewController's view.

```
- (void)showImagePickerForPhotoLibrary {
NSLog(@"Picker");
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    UIViewController *containerController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    containerController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(768, 1000);

    [containerController.view addSubview:imagePickerController.view];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController");
        if (cls != nil) {
            popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:containerController];

            [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:selectedRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:4 animated:YES];


            [imagePickerController.view setFrame:containerController.view.frame];
        }
    }
    else {
        [app.mainViewController presentModalViewController:containerController animated:YES];
    }   
}
```

Hope this helps

EDIT: for some strange reason, the frame does indeed change when in landscape right.

To come over this, you need to set the image picker's view's frame after you present the popover.

I have edited the code above to show this.

Also, in your controller, add this:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

    [imagePickerController.view setFrame:imagePickerController.view.superview.frame];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway I can get the width and height of the iPad for the line containerController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(768, 1000); ?

Comment: The ipad resolution is 768x1024. If you want the popover to take up the whole screen, try CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)

Comment: This sort of works, but causes another (strange) bug : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422636/black-bar-in-uiimagepicker-on-ipad-only-in-landscape-right-orientation

Answer (score 0):

When I tried Mutix's solution the popover showed just the navigation bar with an empty white view.

My way around it was to add imagePickerController as a child of containerController and not just adding the picker's view.

Mainly it means to replace this line:

```
[containerController.view addSubview:imagePickerController.view];
```

with these lines:

```
[containerController addChildViewController:imagePickerController];
[containerController.view addSubview:imagePickerController.view];
[imagePickerController didMoveToParentViewController:containerController];
```

In addition, when using this approach, I didn't need any special handling for landscape mode.